# Where can I find a list of sources for D&D 4E?

Tags: dnd-4e, tools

Where can I find a resource that will let me look up the name of *something* (mostly mechanical) and find out which supplement it came from? I don't need stats or anything else that is restricted, just a place to start looking.

I'm thinking an article in the resource would read something like:

> **Warlock**
>
> *First appearence*: PhB
>
> *Subsequent appearences*: Splat book 2B, Dragon magazine X-Y

Does something like this exist? Bonus points if it's free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Compendium on http://www.wizards.com/dnd

The downside is that it requires you to get an insider account. However, the upside is that the insider account makes building and managing character insanely easy.

There are other good resources for both players and DMs including encounter building, Dungeon Mag and Dragon Articles and more.

Have your group pitch in and everyone can use it. Then it is extremely affordable.

Comment: I should have mentioned I was looking for something free! Good suggestion though.

Comment: @Pureferret while to get detailed information, you need to pay, the Compendium search feature is free, and will tell you which source things come from. I use it all the time, and don't have an account with DDI

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure with the way the GSL works, the compendium is about all you're going to get unless someone has personally put one of these together. Which if they have, it won't be long before WotC sends a C&D letter along with other various legal implications their way.

In my 2+ years of obsessing over 4e, I do not believe something like this exists. You can use the search function on the D&D site but even their search function sucks, perhaps browse the archive by category? Best of luck to you!

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to explain how the GSL differs form the OGL?

Comment: I don't know all of the specifics but I do know that the GSL is some strange machination of legalese, copyright, and bits of sinew left over from the OGL. There's a good series of articles on it entitled ["Protection from Chaos"](http://www.loremaster.org/content.php/123-protection-from-chaos?s=95a9990dd58c69b80a0dd171fa6354c7) over on Loremaster.org

Comment: I'm no lawyer, but I'm pretty sure that merely compiling an index of resources is far from a copyright infringement.

Comment: @SimonWithers do you know if such a thing exists somewhere?